# Serialize a strange js object

Tags: javascript, json, string, serialization

I got a js object, if I use the `console.log`, the result is like this:

```
{ title: 'testCase',
  id: '5e41538bbf4a7e93a12925a3e6ca12',
  links:
   [ URLLink {
       link: 'www.google.com' } ] 
}
```

but If I use console.log("sometext" + wireObj);

The result is :

> sometext[object Object]

If I use `JSON.stringify()`, the result will become:

```
{ title: 'testCase',
  id: '5e41538bbf4a7e93a12925a3e6ca12',
  links:
   [{
       link: 'www.google.com' }] 
}
```

As you can see, the `URLLink` is missing, I would like to preserve this information as well. Any comments?

Comment: JSON does not have built in type information. you should consider adding a type hint property.

Comment: I think that you forgot `:` symbol. You need this: `[ URLLink:  {
       link: 'www.google.com' } ] `

Comment: What you are trying to do is serialize an INVALID javascript object

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is model links as an array of `URLLink` objects then maybe you could do it like this:

`{ title: 'testCase',
  id: '5e41538bbf4a7e93a12925a3e6ca12',
  links:
   [ {URLLink: {link: 'www.google.com' }},
     {URLLink: {link: 'www.yahoo.com' }} ] 
}`

Note the curly braces wrapping `URLLink` and the colon mentioned by @alexandru-ionut-mihai

That would be parsed like below:

[image: Parsed Json]